# Slug url -- what's needed in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Quick question.

I created a slug method in my Posts Controller so that @post.slug returns (ex) "this-is-the-post-name".

Not sure what to do in my routes.rb file, though, to make it work ('posts/this-is-the-post-name'), and I didn't find a question or guide that quite fit the answer. Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it's always a good learning experience to roll your own, it may be more practical to use a gem that does handles slugging. I generally turn to `FriendlyId` as it is actively developed and has lots of great options and makes slugging very simple.

[FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Answer (score 6):

you don't need to add anything in the routes if you've already set up the resources.  If not, all you need in your routes is

```
resources :posts
```

then, to use the slug as the parameter, you need to define a `to_param` method in your post model.

```
# post.rb
def to_param
  slug
end
```

this method is called by url_for to convert objects to urls. for example

```
>> @post.slug = 'this-is-the-post-name'
>> post_path(@post) = '/posts/this-is-the-post-name'
```

one more thing you have to take note is fetching records. since the url doesn't include the ids of the posts anymore, you have to search by slug. for example, in the show action

```
def show
  # this will not work anymore
  # @post = Post.find params[:id]
  # you should change this to
  @post = Post.find_by_slug params[:id]
end
```

Comment: Actually you can get `find` to work by overriding ARs find_one method, which is what eventually gets called from find. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/4.0.9/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb

Comment: you are right. but it's easier to tell the OP to change the process of finding the record than to override AR methods which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since there's an easy gem out there, I think I'm going to pass on the homebrewed version this time (particularly, since I don't want to make a slug column in my model). Thanks, though!

Comment: Well, maybe, actually. That looks not too bad, and I generally prefer lightweight. Thanks for all the options!

Comment: nope, i'm totally ok with it. though you still need to add a slug column if you're going to use friendlyid :)

Answer (score 5):

expanding on jvnill's answer, make sure that slug is a column on your posts table and should be unique or you're going to have problems.